# Get variable value in subset function - R

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

I found an issue while trying to get the value of a variable in the subset function. When I run the code, I receive the message: "Warning: Error in -: invalid argument to unary operator" because "val" in subset function "-c(val)" not define as variable above.

```
cname <- c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","A10",
           "A11","A12","A13","A14","A15","A16","A17","A18","A19","A20",
           "A21","A22","A23","A24","A25","A26","A27","A28","A29","A30","A31")
    
for (i in 15:length(cname)) {
    val <- cname[i]
    ifelse(sum(!is.na(df2$val))==0, 
           df2 <- subset(df2, select = -c(val)), 
           df2)
}
```

The df2 results in [this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOpmt.png).

My expected result is to remove unnecessary columns that have NA values only, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pCkf.png).

How can I get the value from val, so I can remove the columns that have only NA values?

Comment: Never ever ever try to use `<-` assignment in an `ifelse`. It is an abuse of the function, and even if it came close to working (it does not), the _principle_ of the vectorized `ifelse` is confusing in the context of vectorized assignment.

Comment: I'm having a hard time even interpreting what _could_ be happening here. Please try to explain what you are expecting in the end (an explicit "expected output" would be very useful here).

Comment: I have a dataframe which has column in cname, i want to check and exclude some columns with has NA value only. My problem is i can't get the "val" value as variable in subset. can you tell me the solution or the another way to make it clear

Comment: It would help to see (1) the contents of `df2` (plain text _e.g._ using `dput(df2)`) and (2) the expected output (also plain text).

Comment: @alf001, you have a vector `cname` which I'm inferring reflects a column in a frame. I don't understand how that connects to *"exclude some columns which has NA value only"*. Please provide a fully reproducible example, including a frame (with 2-3 columns that you need to update) and the same frame _updated_. Literal data is very much appreciated, as describing what you want does not really clear it up for me.

Comment: My post already edited to provide image of df2 and expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `subset` without a loop - use the vectorized `colSums` on a logical matrix (`is.na(df2)`) to return the count of NAs in each column, compare (`!=`) it with the number of rows (`nrow(df2)`) to create a logical vector, subset the column names, use that in `select` argument in `subset`

```
subset(df2, select = names(df2)[colSums(is.na(df2)) != nrow(df2)])
```

-output

```
 A1 A2 A4 A5
1  1  1 NA 10
2  2  2 NA 10
3  3  3 NA 10
4  4 NA  3 10
5  5  5  2 10
```

---

Or with `tidyverse` - use `select` and check for `any` non-NA elements in each column for selecting the column

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
   select(where(~ any(!is.na(.x))))
```

-output

```
  A1 A2 A4 A5
1  1  1 NA 10
2  2  2 NA 10
3  3  3 NA 10
4  4 NA  3 10
5  5  5  2 10
```

#### data

```
df2 <- data.frame(A1 = 1:5, A2 = c(1:3, NA, 5), A3 = NA_integer_,
     A4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 2), A5 = 10)
```